# select n rows, evaluate a condition, swap the columns if met using R

Tags: r

I have a situation that I am curious to know how R can handle efficiently. let's say I have a data set that has two columns-V1 and V2.
Now, I want a way to evaluate column V1 and check in 3 rows at a time (i.e rows 1 to 3, then 4 to 6 and so on) for the following two conditions:-
a) do either of the 3 rows of V1 contain zero
b) do either of 3 rows of V1 contains a three digit number

if the conditions meet, then we swap the 3 values in V1 column with the values in V2.

I am struggling to find a way to do this in R. This has to be done over 500,000 rows and 5 columns, so efficiency would be important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet very proficient with R, but here's a way;

```
# Sample data
df = data.frame(col1=c(1,0,3,4,5,6,107,8,9), col2=c(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))

#   col1 col2
# 1    1    9
# 2    0    8
# 3    3    7
# 4    4    6
# 5    5    5
# 6    6    4
# 7  107    3
# 8    8    2
# 9    9    1

# Function to evaluate condition ==0 or 3 digits    
cond <- function(x) { any(x==0 | x>=100 & x<=999); }

# Add column telling whether to swap by running the cond function over groups
# of three. Expand the groups again by repeating each value 3 times to match
# the rows.
df$swap = rep(lapply(split(df$col1, ceiling(seq_along(df$col1)/3)), FUN=cond), each=3)

# Swap the indicated rows
df[df$swap==TRUE,][c('col1', 'col2')] = df[df$swap==TRUE,][c('col2', 'col1')]

# Remove the swap column
df <- within(df, rm(swap))

#   col1 col2
# 1    9    1
# 2    8    0
# 3    7    3
# 4    4    6
# 5    5    5
# 6    6    4
# 7    3  107
# 8    2    8
# 9    1    9
```

I'm not very fond of adding the swap column to the frame, however I'm not quite sure how to avoid it.

Comment: tested it on my dataset and it does work well..cheers!